# How to get the logits for the T5 model when using the `generate` method for inference?

Tags: nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I'm currently using HuggingFace's T5 implementation for text generation purposes. More specifically, I'm using the `T5ForConditionalGeneration` to solve a text classification problem as generation.

The model's performance is overall very satisfactory after training, but what I am wondering is how I can get the logits for generation?

I'm currently performing inference as is suggested in the documentation via `model.generate(**tokenizer_outputs)`, but this simply outputs the IDs themselves without anything else.

The reason why I want the logits is because I want to measure the model's confidence of generation. I'm not 100% certain if my approach is correct, but I'm thinking that if I can get the logit values of each generated token and average them, I could get the overall confidence score of the generated sequence.

Would anybody know how I could do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was struggling with this because I wasn't familiar with how the Transformers library works, but after looking at the source code all you have to do is set the arguments `output_scores` and `return_dict_in_generate` to `True`.

For more information, take a look at the method [`transformers.generation.utils.GenerationMixin.generate`](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/ba9da49aa298345022f35a0b7be44ce4c72b85c2/src/transformers/generation/utils.py#L999).